# Look up a value in a table based on two input values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am very familiar with `vlookup` and `hlookup` functions in Excel.  However, I am looking for a method of doing both.  Take this example:

```
        A             B        C  
1                     Resources
2   Task            Mgr   Sr. Mgr
3   -----------------------------
4   Task 1          30%       70%
5   Task 2          40%       60%
6   Task 3          50%       50%
7   Task 4          70%       30%
```

If I wanted to put a formula in a new cell to look up both a task and a resource type to return the appropriate percentage, how could I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of INDEX and MATCH will do the trick:

> =INDEX($B$4:$C$7,MATCH("Task 3",$A$4:$A$7,0),MATCH("Mgr",$B$2:$C$2,0))

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility:

```
=VLOOKUP(E3,A2:C7,MATCH(E2,A2:C2,0),FALSE)
```

Where

- E3 contains the task to look up
- E2 contains the header column name
  (eg Mgr)
- A2:A7 is the table of data
- A2:C2 is the header

Comment: Remou - Thanks. I tried this approach but ran into problems, seemingly because I had additional columns between A and B in your example. The data returned was from columns B-E even though I was looking for M-P. Still gave you an upvote though!

Answer (score 1):

```
=OFFSET(A3,MATCH("Task 3", A4:A7, 0),MATCH("Mgr",B2:C2,0))
```

Of course, you're probably getting the things to look for from other cells, so replace "Task 3" and "Mgr" above with references to those cells.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, assume you have an Excel sheet with the following format where your lookup table occupies the cell range A1:E5

```
     C1    C2    C3    C4
R1  R1C1  R1C2  R1C3  R1C4
R2  R2C1  R2C2  R2C3  R2C4
R3  R3C1  R3C2  R3C3  R3C4
R4  R4C1  R4C2  R4C3  R4C4
```

Also assume you want to enter the row header name and column header name into cells G3 and H3 respectively (which I have the text values "R3" and "C2").

In the cell you wish to display your output value, you could either use HLOOKUP like so:

```
=HLOOKUP(H3,A1:E5,MATCH(G3,A1:A5,0))
```

or VLOOKUP like so:

```
=VLOOKUP(G3,A1:E5,MATCH(H3,A1:E1,0))
```

Either displays the value "R3C2" in my output cell.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this approach but ran into problems, seemingly because I had additional columns between A and B in your example.  The data returned was from columns B-E even though I was looking for M-P.  Still gave you an upvote though!

Answer (score 1):

Okokokok so

I just figured out an alternate, much simpler answer... its an IF function!
so okay, what I mean by this is the following;

you have 2 input cells, both formatted with data validation lists. One has the tasks, and one has the position, as shown in the question asked.

now we use a vlookup function to determine what row we are going to get, and then an IF function to determine the column!!

now lets say your input cells are next to each other at E1 and F1

So an example of this formula would be,

=vlookup($E$1,$A$4:$C$7,IF($F$1="MGR",2,3),FALSE)

This works so well and can even be used with more than 2 columns by using the IFS Function!

I Hope this helps some kid in the future who did exactly what I did and went to the internet for answers after being very confused hahaha

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Using INDEX/MATCH would be even better.